# Keep slideToggle() div open after page refresh?

Tags: jquery

I have a form which is hidden using slideToggle(). What I need to do is allow the user to view the form once clicking the 'show form' link, fill out the form and hit submit. Then, if there are any errors allow the page to refresh with the div still showing.

In other words how do I prevent slideToggle() from resetting on the page refresh. As otherwise the user has to then show the form again in order to see errors. I'm just using a basic PHP_SELF with some code on this rather than AJAX as I want to keep it dead simple.

Here is my current JS:

```
$('a#booknow').click(function() {
$('#formcontain').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('houdini');
});
return false;
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider requesting the page with a query string or hash (like `#showform` or `?showform=1`), instead of simply refreshing it. That way, you can test for the existence of said query string or hash and show/hide your form based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a cookie, and additionally I'd use a [plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) (as writing client-side cookie management code makes my head hurt).

```
$('a#booknow').click(function() {
    $('#formcontain').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('houdini');
    });
    $.cookie('form_visible', $('#formcontain').is(':visible').toString());
    return false;
});
```

Then on page load:

```
$(function() {
    if($.cookie('form_visible') == 'true') {
        $('#formcontain').show();
    } else {
        $('#formcontain').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan that worked a treat in conjunction with the jQuery cookie plugin found here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 1):

To save a state, you should probably use a client-side storage, for example, cookies.
You can save the state of JS in a SESSION variable (bet then you need to somehow tell PHP what is the state, perhaps, using ajax).